# Filtering Material-Table with remote Data doesn't work with query.filters

Tags: c#, reactjs, rest, axios, material-ui

I made a table with MaterialTable in react.
In this table I have to make a call to the back end every time we filter a column.
Currently the code is as follows:

```
<MaterialTable
                style={{fontFamily:'Roboto'}}
                icons={tableIcons}
                title={""}
                columns={columns}
                data={(query) =>
                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    let url = "/items/orders?";
                    url += "pageSize=" + query.pageSize;
                    url += "&pageIndex=" + (query.page + 1);
                    url += query.filters.length >0 ? query.filters.map(z => "filter=" + z.column.field + z.operator + z.value):"";

                    axios.get(url)
                      .then(res => {
                        sessionStorage.setItem("data", res.data);
                        resolve({
                         data: res.data.data,
                          page: res.data.pageIndex - 1,
                          totalCount: res.data.count
                        });
                      })
                  })
                }   
                options={{
                  sorting:true,
                  search: false,
                  filtering:true,
                  actionsColumnIndex:-1,
                  pageSize:10,
                  exportButton: true,
                  exportDelimiter:';',
                  exportFileName: 'WO list',
                  exportAllData: true,
                  // filtering: enableFilteringVariable, 
                  //padding:'dense',
                  draggable:true,
                  columnsButton:true
                }}
 />
```

the filter on the back end is applied like this:

```cs
var items = await query.Where(filter) 
                       .OrderBy(orderBy)
                       .Skip(pageSize * pageIndex)
                       .Take(pageSize)
                       .ToListAsync();
```

But when the api is called it returns "data not found" because a search is carried out based on the filter of each single entered character (type: "name = a")
Also I shouldn't do a specific search but type "**LIKE**"

How can I prevent making a call for every single entered character?

How can I filter the api data more generically like for SQL with the **LIKE** operator?